# How do I align correctly with Linearlayout and weight parameter?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I need to know how do I align these three last buttons in order to be aligned according to the buttons above.

I going to show you a screen capture about I'm saying.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="@string/b_zero" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/b_punto" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/b_signo_mas" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: this is the output of the code above]

Like you can see, I want to align the zero button combining two columns using the weight parameter.

Comment: How about `android:weightSum=4` and then 2/1/1 distribution along with `android:layout_width=0dp`.

Comment: Cool, thanks dude, it works perfectly @Shaishav

Comment: Seriously! That was it?

Comment: yep, I didn't know that it was required to put 0dp of witdh in each button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that distribution by specifying a `android:layoutSum=4` and then distributing the weight as 2/1/1 among the child views. Be sure to specify `android:layout_width=0dp` for each of those children.

When using `android:layout_weight` property, always remember to put `0dp` as the dimension corresponding to the orientation along which you are specifying the weights.